# My flag weight is an illogical value

Tags: bug, flagging, flag-weight

From my understanding of how flag weights work, the flag weight should always be a multiple of 5, as you get ±10 for posts and ±5 for comments. My flag weight is currently "537.2867". How on earth did this happen, and why? It seems quite illogical.

[image: illogical flag weight]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Between 0 and 500, it's a set +5 or +10 points for each valid flag (negative if invalid).

Once you crack the 500 mark, [it becomes wibbly-wobbly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117):

> - start at 100
> - +10 for a flagged post (+5 for a comment) that we did something about (or was basically valid)
> - -10 for a flagged post (-5 for a comment) that we suppressed as invalid
> - min 0, max 750 **(but non-linear above 500)**
> - IMPORTANT CHANGE - if you flag so consistently badly that you reach 0 weight, flags will be suppressed

Comment: Hmm. So it's supposed to be non-linear then, but should it really be showing that many significant figures? Something tells me that having decimal places on flag weights really isn't necessary.

Comment: You're correct. There should be many more decimal places in the flag weighting @nhi

Comment: What? More? No, I think there should be fewer... unless you're kidding, I'm really not sure.

Comment: Assume no jokes from the likes of moderators @nhi

Comment: I think I'll revisit this when I've had more sleep and can tell if you're _actually_ serious or not. I honestly can't right now.

Comment: @random if you want more DP, just hover...

Comment: Your concept of more DP is paltry. Needs more D in the P. @mar

Answer (score 4):

> as you get ±10 for posts and ±5 for comments

That is true up to 500, but not true *beyond* 500.